# What is RHW in DirectX Vertex

Tags: c++, directx, vertex

I know RHW is Reciprocal Homogeneous W, but could someone explain how it can be used and what it does ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explanation on gamedev forum [post](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/440283-reciprocal-of-homogeneous-w/) and [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206341%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

to quote the answer from gamedev, OP [jpetrie](https://www.gamedev.net/profile/46720-josh-petrie/):

> RHW is the reciprocal of the homogeneous (clip space) w coordinate of
>   a vertex (e.g., 1/w).
>
> Recall that we must expand our 3D vectors to 4D vectors in order to be
>   able to multiply them with 4x4 matrices (which we do because 4x4
>   matrices allow us to completely encode both rotational, translational,
>   and scaling terms). In doing so we often set (or assume) the expanded
>   fourth (w) component is 1 for model vertices, and the nature of the
>   transforms we use to bring model-space vertices into world or view
>   space doesn't include any terms that alter the w component.
>
> However, the typical perspective projection transformation often takes
>   the follow general form
>
> A 0 0 0  0 B 0 0  0 0 C D 0 0 E 0
>
> which, when multiplied with a general view-space vertex vector
>   (x,y,z,1), gives you a vector like (Ax, By, Cz + E, zD) -- note that
>   the resulting vertex has a w component that is proportional to the
>   original input's z component. Also note that the space you're in after
>   multiplication by this matrix is called clip space, because the nature
>   of the transform has distorted the viewing frustum into a cuboid, the
>   edges of which are much easier to perform clipping against.
>
> After clipping, the graphics pipeline divided by the w component to
>   scale things based on distance to give you the perspective effect.
>   This division cannot be encoded in a matrix transform.
>
> Now, division by w is the same as multiplication by the reciprocal of
>   w, and the reason that you are required to give the reciprocal of the
>   clip space w coordinate is probably a throwback to the time when
>   division was significantly slower than multiplication. When you use
>   pre-transformed vertices, the transformation from model to world to
>   view to clip space is skipped, but the rest of the pipeline (division
>   by w, conversion to window coordinates, and rasterization, obviously)
>   must still happen. Since the projection transform was skipped, there
>   is no basis for the pipeline to determine the w coordinate to divide
>   by, so it asks you for it.
>
> There are some interesting uses for the value, but for the most part
>   people use pretransformed vertices when doing 2D rendering, and in
>   that case its most useful to set the RHW value to 1, which effectively
>   causes the divide to be a no-op.