# Why does RHW is necessary in D3D

Tags: opengl, graphics, directx

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954152/what-is-rhw-in-directx-vertex) but I still don't know why we use rhw in D3D.

Here is my opinion:

In opengl, we find that when we map a point from frustum to near plane, there is always a coefficient "(-)z", so we assume that w in clip space is (-)z. This fact told me that for a specific point, w can only have 2 possible values. Before projection transform, it is 1 because we just expanded it to 4d. After we transformed it to clip space, the w should be (-)z.

In the question above, the answer mentioned that if we use pre-transformed vertrices, the rest of pipeline still need a rhw to convert to window coordinate (In paragraph 6). But by the process above, w should be (-)z. So the only reason for using rhw, I think, is division is slow. It can be a reason, but just sounds like too meaningless, because I can handle this manually. Am I wrong?

Comment: "RHW" in the context of the vertex format with that name isn't _necessary_ in D3D, it's a relict from the outdated fixed function pipeline days which has zero relevance today (and it even back then was only necessary if you wanted to bypass that pipeline). `1/w` in general is very relevant in computer graphics and GPUs, as that is what we can linearly interpolate in window space, and it is no conincidence that `glFragCoord.w` contains the recirpocal value. But what this question really is asking is unclear to me.

Comment: " But by the process above, w should be (-)z." That matrix can set up anything for w, but the more probelamtic part is that while `w_clip = -z_eye` in a standard GL projection matrix, still `z_eye != z_clip` and you don't have `z_eye` if you have pre-transformed data

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was very nervous cause this is my first time asking question here because my english is terrible. seems like I failed lol. My question is, why opengl doesn't have a recirpocal value of w_clip because I really didn't know gl_FragCoord.w is recirpocal value before you mentioned it. I did know 1/w is useful, so now I understand it, Thank you.

Comment: But I maybe have something questionable there
**the more probelamtic part is that while w_clip = -z_eye in a standard GL projection matrix, still z_eye != z_clip**
I do know z_eye != z_clip cause the transformation of z is non-linear therefore it can't be recoverd by perspective division. So setting w_clip = -z.eye is just for convenience of perspective divsion, isn't it? the next question is if I have a pre-transformed data, I think I can get z_eye by inversing projection if I know the detail of projection(do you mean that I can't get z_eye becauese projection matrix can't be ensured?)

Comment: First of all: We are still talking about a random detail of some completely outdated D3D version, with zero relevance toady, and second: "I think I can get z_eye by inversing projection if I know the detail of projection" Yes, you can do that, but why should the GPU or render API do that? You would end up having to give that information to that stage, in effect giving it pre-transformed data and having it undo the transformation, just to calculate a value which it doesn't need, because the value it really needs is `w` anyway. What is the point?